# swagger - annotation for permissions?

Tags: servicestack

Is there any way to document the permissions required for a Request? If I have annotations like

```
[Authenticate]
[RequiredRole("Admin")]
[RequiredPermission("CanAccess")]
public object Delete(DeleteAppUser deleteUserRequest)
{
   // ....
}
```

in my service class or alternatively for my RequestDTOs

```
[Authenticate]
[RequiredRole("Admin")]
[Route("/appusers/{AppUserId}", "DELETE", Summary = "Delete an application user identified by its ID.")]
public class DeleteAppUser : IReturn<AppUserDto>
{
    // ....
}
```

Can I make this somehow available in the swagger-ui documentation for users of my API automatically or do I have to write it in the Notes like:

```
[Route("/appusers/{AppUserId}", "DELETE", Summary = "Delete an application user identified by its ID.", Notes="Requires an authenticated session and membership in the Admin role.")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Swaggers UI doesn't have a concept of roles or permissions. This information is displayed on ServiceStack's [/metadata pages](http://docs.servicestack.net/metadata-page) but to display it in Swagger's UI you'd need to add it to the API's text description.